# Prove that $\operatorname{lcm}(ak, bk) = k \cdot \operatorname{lcm}(a, b) $.

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that $\operatorname{lcm}(ak, bk) = k \cdot \operatorname{lcm}(a, b) $.

How to prove the above statement? I have tried writing out the lcm relationships as a series of 'divides' relationships but to little avail (namely $a\mid \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ ...etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\operatorname{lcm}(a, b)$. $x$ is a multiple of $a$ and $b$, and hence $xk$ is a multiple of $ak$ and $bk$. This gives $$\operatorname{lcm}(ak, bk) \leq \operatorname{lcm}(a, b)k.$$

Now let $\operatorname{lcm}(ak, bk)=y$. Since $y$ is a multiple of $k$, we can write $y=x'k$. $y$ is a multiple of both $ak$ and $bk$, implying that $x'$ is a multiple of both $a$ and $b$. That is, $$\operatorname{lcm}(a, b)\leq \operatorname{lcm}(ak, bk) /k.$$

Combining the two results, we have $\operatorname{lcm}(ak, bk)=\operatorname{lcm} (a, b) k.$